# Report Builder - Reporting in Multiple Languages

Tags: oracle, delphi, reportbuilder

I need to create 2 reports in ReportBuilder which produce identical output except that one report needs to produce English text and the other in French. The labels/headings on the report will need to be translated from English to French and in some cases the data returned will also have to be translated.

I was thinking about doing this by creating the English statement as a base class then inheriting from this to create the French report, changing the labels as necessary. My question is how is the best way to go about translating the data itself?

I am using Delphi BDS 2006, Oracle 11g and ReportBuild v10

Comment: Que diriez-vous Google translate?

Comment: Google translate API är en betaltjänst.

Comment: In professional software development circles its customary to pay a human being to translate it rather than putting it through a software translation system.  Human beings can validate that the results make sense.  If you don't mind your french report being laughable, then go ahead and use a machine translation.  But you know all those laughable signs in China that use rude phrases and/or rediculous mis-use of english words?  Automatic translation.  Just saying.  It would be typical to have your template files stored on disk, with language ISO code stored as part of your filename.

Comment: Please clarify if you mean Digital Metaphors ReportBuilder or Oracle Report Builder?

Comment: Dans le développement logiciel professionnel tourne autour de son usage de payer un être humain pour qu'il soit traduit plutôt que de le mettre à travers un système de traduction de logiciels. Les êtres humains peuvent valider que les résultats ont un sens. Si vous n'avez pas l'esprit de votre rapport françaises étant risible, alors allez-y et utilisez une traduction automatique. Mais vous savez tous ces signes dérisoires en Chine qui utilisent des phrases grossières et / ou ridicule mauvaise utilisation de mots anglais? La traduction automatique. Il suffit de dire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of language translation in Oracle. You will need to create a tool which would do this for you. You can "try" using Oracle webservices and Google translate to make it work. Since, Google translation API is paid service, you can try the free Bing Translation web service. It should be fairly easy to code, follow [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110720142541/http://basharkokash.com/post/2010/04/19/Bing-Translator-for-developers.aspx) link and [this](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) link for more details.

Comment: I don't see why the fact that the back end database is Oracle has anything to do with how translation for a ReportBuilder report would work, so even if Oracle had some translation features, you probably couldn't access them in ReportBuilder. It is a third party tool that is database agnostic. http://www.digital-metaphors.com

Comment: Errm.... Oracle Reports builder is not a third party tool, it is an Oracle product and can very well access DB objects, packages, procedures, functions et cetra...

Comment: Okay, maybe I thought he meant the common "Reports Builder" tool, not "Oracle Reports", which I have only thus far seen called "Oracle Reports Developer", or just "Oracle Reports", but not "Oracle Reports Builder".  here on stack overflow the tag `[reportbuilder]` definitely refers to Digital Metaphor's product, not any oracle thing. However I did some googling, and it seems that the term "Report Builder" is DEFINITELY used by Oracles own docs. ie here: http://docs.oracle.com/html/A73172_01/output/bawor_si.htm